# Table caption indentation

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

My caption is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{3pt}%
    \colorbox{astrol-blue}{{#1}}#2#3
} 

\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=white}}
```

and inside the table I do

```
\captionsetup{type=table, format=labelstyle}
```

With what command can I slightly indent the caption so the blue box is left-aligned with `\hline` of my table?

Comment: Maybe add `\hskip\fboxsep` just before `\colorbox{…}` in \DeclareCaptionFormat? Or use the key `margin=\fboxsep`?

Comment: The key `margin=\fboxsep` would belong into the `\captionsetup`?

Comment: Yes, I  would do so (I didn't test it: it's only a suggestion).